# forcing navigator.online to false when running tests

Tags: javascript, testing, ember.js, acceptance-testing, ember-testing

I'm writing acceptance tests for an ember application and the application works offline.
I wanted to know if there was a way to force navigator.online to false to test certain behaviours when running tests.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use mocking.

Wrap the code `navigator.online` in a service or a utility class. Use that class in your application. Use a mock implementation of this service for your tests.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Ember.testing` which will be true only when you are running in testing mode.

Comment: my problem is that the application is already written with navigator.onLine checks to change behaviour if it's in offline mode. I can't change that code.